# Autenticação Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

eu desenvolvi um app Android + Firebase (autenticação + storage + database). Enquanto esta nos testes no Android Studio + smartphone autêntica e funciona perfeitamente. Publiquei terça passada e depois que estava na loja baixei para testar (como um dos meus possíveis usuários faria) e quando tentei autenticar apareceu o seguinte erro na foto.

[image: erro autenticação com num telefone]

Já atualizei a chave SHA-1 no Firebase, o package name esta correto no Firebase e no Play Console.

Comment: Tente proceder como na resposta nesse link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application

Comment: [verifique essa configuração de sh-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application) Tente proceder como na resposta nesse link.

Comment: [configuração de sh1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application) creio que isso resolva

Answer (score 0):

Tente sincronizar sua chave de autenticação com o firebase pelo android studio pelo seguinte caminho:

```
Tools>Firebase>Authentication>Connect>Sync
```

Acredito que sua chave esteja desatualizada (***release.keystore.jks***) ou não tenha copiado o arquivo ***google-services.json*** para a pasta do app.

Comment: Já esta sincronizado, e tbm ja baixei e copiei o arquivo google-services.json para a pasta , compilei e atualizei na loja e mesmo assim continua apresentando esse erro

Comment: neste caso receio não poder lhe ajudar... eu tentaria excluir o projeto no firebase console e recadastrar um novo, cadastrando atentamente o ***package name*** e a chave de ***release*** (existem 2 chaves, uma para *debug* e outra para *release*). Boa sorte!

Comment: Ja fiz isso tbm, so nao exclui da loja e publiquei novamente